Removing pink noise from time series
How can I go about removing pink noise from a time series of which I know that it contains pink noise?
My idea would be to work with least squares linear approximation in the frequency domain, but would prefer working in the time domain.
Question:
how can pink noise be removed from a potentially infinite time series with values from an a priory known interval [a,b] ?
